# why does memory leak still occur with ARC?Does it matter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-leaks

I used instruments to measure my app.It shows some memory leaks and my app is with ARC.

Here is a picture of the leak.

[image]

Question is:

1.We can see the size of memory leak is about 1KiB,most of it is smaller.Does it matter if I do not care about it?

2.We can see the address of the instance where memory leak happens,can I locate it (in the code,i suppose),so I can fix it,and how?

Answer (score 0):

because there may be the use of strong instances of objects, that are not getting released. And always use weak references under blocks.

**For Example**

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        weakSelf.drawingView.center = weakSelf.center;
    });
```

there can also be retain cycles.
Please use call trees for solution . then analyse code as well.